# How to have init values for a selection interval in Altair when using dates?

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to have initial values for a selection_interval in a Altair plot, but I've been unable to figure it out.

Here is a code snippet:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2005-03-01', 1: '2005-04-01', 2: '2005-05-02'}, 
                   'values': {0: 89.2506, 1: 109.4073, 2: 120.8222}})

interval = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'],init = {'x':['2005-03-01', '2005-04-01']})

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(x =  alt.X('date:T'), y = alt.Y('values')).add_selection(interval)
```

I expected the area between '2005-03-01' and '2005-04-01' to be highlighted when the plot initializes.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Vega-Lite is not recognizing and converting timestamps within the `init` argument. You can get around this by using Pandas to convert the dates to timestamps manually:

```
x_init = pd.to_datetime(['2005-03-01', '2005-04-01']).astype(int) / 1E6
interval = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'], init={'x':list(x_init)})
```

Comment: It seems this is not working in altair `5.0.1`. Getting this:
```
 parameter.param = core.SelectionParameter(
    404         name=parameter.name, bind=bind, value=value, expr=expr, **kwds
    405     )
    406     parameter.param_type = "selection"
    408 return parameter

TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'value'
```
Didn't find any alternative in the docs...

Comment: I got `TypeError: altair.vegalite.v5.schema.core.SelectionParameter() got multiple values for keyword argument 'value'` as error.
I had to change the example to `alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'], value={'x': [0, 10]})` (i.e. `init` -> `value`) to make it work.