# Setting the default Altair selection interval domain

Tags: altair

I can setup an Altair chart with a secondary chart as the selection interval.  What I need to be able to do is set the initially displayed interval to be less than the full scale.

The example I'm working from is below:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

weather = data.seattle_weather()
weather.head()

interval = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])


base = alt.Chart(weather).mark_rule(size=2).encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='temp_min:Q',
    y2='temp_max:Q',
    color='weather:N'
)

chart = base.encode(
    x=alt.X('date:T', scale=alt.Scale(domain=interval.ref()))
).properties(
    width=800,
    height=300
)

view = base.add_selection(
    interval
).properties(
    width=800,
    height=50,
)

chart & view
```

I assume I need to add some other parameters into encodings of `interval = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])`, but I'm too new to Altair to understand where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try your code because I don't know what the `weather` data looks like, but if I understand you correctly, your issue could be solved by setting the `value` (`init` in altair <5) parameter of the selection interval:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()
brush = alt.selection_interval(value={'y': [20, 40]})

alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color=alt.condition(brush, 'Cylinders:O', alt.value('grey')),
).add_params(brush)
```

[image]

More info in the docs https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#encoding-channel-binding

Comment: I updated the code set.  I was using a standard Altair example, but I should have included everything.  It's from one of the vega_datasets.  I think you've given me the correct parameter I need, but now I just need to figure out how to pass dates into that init parameter.  Thanks.

Comment: I've found a few questions dealing with dates in Altair selection_interval init().  Trying all those solutions is throwing a `'list' object has no attribute 'get'` exception.

Comment: @TimeHorizon There is an answer here for how to use `init` values with dates in Altair https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469922/how-to-have-init-values-for-a-selection-interval-in-altair-when-using-dates. Regarding the error you are getting, you need to download your jsonschema package to 3.x as per https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2496

Comment: Thanks again.  I found that question, but didn't find the items on the error.  Thanks again.

Comment: In altair 5.2 `init` should be replaced with `value`

Comment: @StephenWilliams True, I updated and added a link to the docs which will always have the latest version